# SQL 2008 Bulk Insert & Variable Length Records

Tags: sql-server-2008, csv, import

I'm having issues with 2008 and Bulk Insert.  I can't get it to behave with variable length records (specifically headers).

Given the following file lines:

---

- 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,9,10
- 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,9,10,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,9,10
- 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,9,10,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,9,10
- 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,9,10,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,9,10
- 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,9,10,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,9,10
- 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,9,10,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,9,10
- 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,9,10,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,9,10
- 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,9,10,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,9,10
- 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,9,10,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,9,10
- 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,9,10,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,9,10

Shouldn't the following do something useful like import the data? rather than return an empty table, or error if FirstRow is less than 2?

I can't remember having quite so many issues with importing and SQL 2000.

---

```
   drop table #data

   create table #data
   (    
    a int null, b int null
    ,c int null, d int null
    ,e int null, f int null
    ,g int null, h int null
    ,i int null, j int null
    ,k int null, l int null
    ,m int null, n int null
    ,o int null, p int null
    ,q int null, r int null
    ,s int null, t int null
   ) 
   truncate table #data

   bulk insert #data 
   from 'd:\temp\data.txt'
   WITH(
     TABLOCK
    ,CODEPAGE='RAW'
    ,DATAFILETYPE='char'
    ,FIELDTERMINATOR=','
    ,ROWTERMINATOR='\r\n'
    ,FIRSTROW=2
    )

   select * from #data
```

Forgot to mention, I have tried SSIS with but no difference...obviously I might have used the wrong component.

Oh and I can get 99% there, the bulk inserts everything but the 2nd row :(  But that's no use to anyone!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SQL Server Integration Service (SSIS)` instead of using bulk copy to convert text file to sql server table.

Comment: Tried that, or at least tried the obvious SSIS.  It could well be there is an SSIS method that works...

Answer (score 0):

You can use DTS wizard

its very easy , dts path is given here

http://sqlcopy.blogspot.in/2012/07/bulk-sql-to-sql-sql-to-csv-csv-to-sql.html

Comment: That's using BULK INSERT, and the question is about that not working with variable column count files.